# Root cannot access /dev/urandom

Tags: permissions, root

I am trying to generate a GPG key, and I cannot generate enough entropy. So I installed `rng-tools` and tried following these instructions: https://serverfault.com/questions/214605/gpg-not-enough-entropy

When I am logged in as root, and try to run `rngd -r /dev/urandom` I get the following error: `can't open /dev/random: Permission denied`

I find this disturbing as I am root.

This is Ubuntu on a virtual server (via Parallels I believe.)

Comment: Feeding `/dev/random` from `/dev/urandom` is really not a good idea. `/dev/urandom` is derived from the same entropy pool as `/dev/random`, so you are not generating any additional entropy using this method. [rngd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/rngd.8.html) is designed for feeding `/dev/random` from a *trusted*, *hardware* source. `/dev/urandom` is neither a trusted nor hardware source of new entropy.

Comment: That aside, I don't get any error message when running `sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom`, so I agree that there is some kind of permissions or device issue here.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`?  The error is the former but the command is the latter, and `rngd` source suggests they should be the same.

In any case, `/dev/random` is the correct one; `/dev/urandom` doesn't have a kernel interface for adding entropy, which is why the open fails (not even `root` can force the kernel to allow writes to a non-writable device, although arguably it should produce a more appropriate error like `EINVAL` or maybe `EPERM`).  The kernel will feed `/dev/urandom` from `/dev/random` automatically.

Comment: I tried rngd -r /dev/random and got the same error.

Comment: In that case I'd check that it's the right device node and its permissions (`ls -l /dev/random`) and then check `/var/log/messages` to see if the random driver is complaining.

Comment: The error message is not inconsistent. [`-r`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/rngd.8.html) specifies the hardware entropy source and `-o` specifies the sink. When undefined, `-o` defaults to `/dev/random`.

Comment: /var/log/messages is empty.